# Select all form values in redux-form

Tags: redux-form

I want to get all values from `redux-form`. I can't use `formValueSelector`, because I don't know fields names (I create them dynamically). One solution is to use `store.getState().form[FORM_NAME].values`, but I guess it's a dirty solution, isn't it? If so, is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [`getFormValues`](http://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/Selectors.md/) selector for that.
Or you could just get the values passed to `onSubmit` during form submission.

Comment: Yeah, but when the field was untouched it doesn't comes with values passed to `onSubmit`. Can I get ALL values for current form in `onSubmit` handler?

Comment: Especially I'm talking about boolean fields like checkbox or radio buttons.